# Why cabal repl test loads src modules?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to debug tests with cabal repl and observe strange behavior.

cabal repl is working for the application code.

```
cabal repl
```

but doesn't for test suit:

```
cabal repl tests
```

fails:

```
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/user/myapp/.ghci

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: 
        MyApp.X
        MyApp.Y
        ...

src/MyApp/X.hs:8:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Relude’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘relude-1.0.0.1’.
```

myapp.cabal:

```
name:           myapp
version:        0.5.0
library
  exposed-modules:
      MyApp.X
      MyApp.Y
  hs-source-dirs:
      src

  build-depends:
      relude >=1.0.0.1


test-suite tests
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Driver.hs
  other-modules:
      MyApp.Test.X
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  ghc-options: -rtsopts -threaded 
  build-depends:
      HUnit
    , base
    , myapp
```

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.4.0.0
compiled using version 3.4.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

Due some reason cabal repl loads modules from src folder not from test one. Test suit doesn't depend on relude dependency. It is hidden for test suit and
of course ghc fails.

---

A college recommended workaround:

```
:set -package bytestring
:set -package tasty
:set -package envy
:set -package tasty-hunit
:set -itest
:set -package HUnit

import Tasty (defaultMain) -- this may fail, ignore it
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `cabal repl test:tests`?